# Open a Nativescript Android app from a link in a email

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I would like to open my android application from a link in an email. Searching through Stackoverflow it looks like this can be achieved using a '' which points to a url I control. I'm a little confused how to use this though in the case of an android app built with Nativescript. Is just adding a url that I own with a specific data path the only thing that needs to be done? In which case that brings up an app selector dialog. Can a certain event be fired off when the application is opened this way? Thanks for the help. Below is a sample of what it looks like I need to do.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <!-- Custom Path data -->
        <data
            android:host="www.some.company.com"
            android:path="/something"
            android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to you `main.ts`

```
import app = require("application");
import platform = require("platform");

declare var android: any;

if(!!app.android){
    app.android.on(app.AndroidApplication.activityResumedEvent, function (args) { 
        console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity); 
        console.log(new String(args.activity.getIntent().getAction()).valueOf(), new String(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW).valueOf());
        if(new String(args.activity.getIntent().getAction()).valueOf() ==  new String(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW).valueOf()){
            console.log(args.activity.getIntent().getData()); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works great, but why can't i access to to rest of the component from within this code? I want to use the url which opened the app, but i can't call anything in the component